# Excel color scale - how to insert new rows to fit in existing scale?

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet of phone numbers (columns) and months (rows), and the phone charge values in the data part. I use Excel's color scale to quickly see if one of the lines has an extreme value, so I select the charges per phone, and set a color scale for EACH phone number (e.g. a color scale for B2:B19, another for C2:C19, etc.).

However, each month, I insert a new row, and again need to apply the color scale to the full ranges every time. If I copy and paste a row, I DO get a color scale, but one based only on that row (e.g. adding row 20 gives me a color range of B20, one of C20, etc.). Copying and inserting a row from the existing scale does not work.

Is there any way I can add e.g. row 20, and automatically have the included in the exiting B2:B19 color scale?

Thanks!
Ed Eichman
Cambrils, Spain

Comment: Inserting a row into the middle of the data will expand all of the underlying conditional formatting ranges to include it.  You can insert a row (not at the end), add your data, and sort so that the order is right.  It should have all of the same formatting as before.  If sorting is not an option (maybe formulas point to these cells), you can insert a row at the second to last row, cut the row below, and paste the cut row above the new one.  This gives a new row at the bottom will all the formatting and previous formulas intact.

Comment: @pnuts YES! That is the answer. It does not apply the color scale to the empty cells, and then fills them in correctly. I feel stupid for not having tried that ;-> Thank you!

Comment: @Byron Wall Your solution also works, Byron, thank you very much for the input. I had tried your solution before posting, but the fact that the inserted row had no formatting incorrectly lead me to conclude that they were not getting picked up. After trying pnuts solution, I realized that your solution DOES work (confirmed by putting values into the empty cells), I just hadn't realized it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about conditional formatting, you can use the rule type "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" option with a formula like:

```
=IF(B3=MAX($B$2:$B$3000),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Then set the formatting to bold the highest value in the column.
Copy the above into the conditional formatting for B3, then after saving, use the format painter to paint the rest of the column. The formula will change for each cell in the column to read =IF(b4, =If(b5... with the range of B2:b3000 locked by the dollar signs (anchors)

Comment: As far as I was able to determine, your solution does not work for what I'm trying to do. I'm using Excel's "color scale" formatting, and it does not seem possible to use that with rules. In any case, thanks for reaching out to help, I appreciate it.